# R pandoc() via knitr: How to define a configuration file to make it reflect my commandline Pandoc call?

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc

I cannot find any thorough description of how to define configuration file for a document conversion with the `knitr` package `pandoc()` function. I do know [this](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/pandoc/) document by YIHUI XIE, but still find it difficult to receive an equivalent of the following Pandoc commandline call:

```
pandoc -t slidy -s pander_test.md -o pander_test_slidy.html
```

in `R`.  I tried (with the configurations embedded in my `.md` file):

```
<!--pandoc
t: slidy
s:
o: pander_output_slidy.html
-->
```

And the `R` console said:

```
> pandoc("pander_test.md")
executing pandoc  -t slidy -s -o pander_output_slidy.html -f markdown -t html -o  pander_test.html "pander_test.md"
[1] "pander_test.html"
```

Which:

- looks differently from the commadline Pandoc call I would like to reflect to,
- generates the result different from what I expect (I receive plain `HTML`, *not* slides as I would like to).

Any suggestions / references? Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `pandoc("pander_test.md", format = 'slidy')`, and use the configuration

```
<!--pandoc
s:
o: pander_output_slidy.html
-->
```